# Where can I change the FileZilla font size running under Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, fonts, filezilla

I consider myself to be a pretty savvy computer user, but this one has escaped me. After reading the documentation, the blogs, the wiki, the bug trac I am still at a loss.

Does anyone know how to adjust the font size of the various FileZilla windows?

Any idea or reference to documentation I missed would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have reason to believe it is even possible?

Comment: ** just unfounded hope **

Comment: Are you running it on PC or Mac?

Comment: PC -- question updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this hard to believe... but the filezilla fonts are controlled by the Icon font.

Changed by "Window Color and Appearance"->"Item Icon"->"Font"

**Note:** This will change all the windows explorer fonts as well

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is now set in Windows. Change your windows font size and filezilla will update.

https://forum.filezilla-project.org/viewtopic.php?t=30353